# Duplicate cell values when saving Apache POI Excel document

Tags: java, mysql, excel, apache-poi

I have a strange issue and am wondering if anyone else has encountered this. 
I have a Java servlet that is making two mySQL queries and then creating an Apache POI worksheet using the values returned from the queries. The first query is for a total and the second for a part of the total. I'm then calculating a percentage which is simply part/total*100.

For testing purposes, I'm returning an xml structure to prove that the values are what I'm expecting them to be. The xml structure has the correct values. I'm also retrieving the cell values from the POI worksheet after I've entered them to test and make sure the values stored in the sheet are correct. They are as well.

The problem is, once I write the worksheet out to the Excel file, the cell in the first row representing the total shows the same value as the cell in the second row representing the part. And the third row, representing the percentage, is 1. This third fact is the oddest, because it implies to me that the error is occurring during the percentage calculation procedure, not when writing to the output stream. It's as if two percentage calculations are being done simultaneously, one based on correctly dividing part by total (which shows up in the xml), the other on dividing the part by itself yielding 1 (which shows up in the output Excel sheet). Has anyone had issues similar to this?

I'm including below the doPost code in the servlet:

```
     public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String                  outtype         =   "";
    String                  query           = "";
    String                  querytot        =  "";
    boolean                 bError          = false;
    HttpSession             session         = req.getSession(true);
    StringBuffer            sbResponse      = new StringBuffer("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<response>\n");
    ServletContext          sc              = getServletContext();
    String                  sErrorMessage   = "";
    String                  sErrorCode      = "";
    StringBuffer dbStringBuf = new StringBuffer("");
    outtype =  getStringParameter(req, "outtype", "0");
    querytot =  getStringParameter(req, "querytot", "0"); 
    query = getStringParameter(req, "query", "0"); 

    try {
        Connection con = datasource.getConnection();

        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(querytot); //querying for the total value
        rs.next();
        Object obj = rs.getObject(1);
        dbStringBuf.append("  <whole>\n"); //starting build of xml structure for testing here
        Integer currRowintTot = 0;
        String currRowTot = obj.toString();
        currRowintTot = Integer.parseInt(currRowTot);   
        int tothold = currRowintTot;
        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("mainsheet");
        Row row = sheet1.createRow(1);
        Cell labelcell = row.createCell(0);
        Cell valuecell = row.createCell(1);
        labelcell.setCellValue("Survey Val Whole");
        valuecell.setCellValue(currRowTot); 
        dbStringBuf.append("    <result>"+currRowTotConv+"</result>\n");  
        dbStringBuf.append("   </whole>\n");
        stmt.close();

        stmt2 = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rspart = stmt2.executeQuery(query); //querying for the part value
        rspart.next();
        Object objpart = rspart.getObject(1);
        String currRowPart = objpart.toString();
        dbStringBuf.append("  <part>\n");
        currRowintPart = Integer.parseInt(currRowPart);
        int parthold = currRowintPart;
        dbStringBuf.append("    <result>"+currRowPart+"</result>\n");  
        Row row2 = sheet1.createRow(2);
        Cell labelcellw = row2.createCell(0);
        Cell valuecellw = row2.createCell(1);
        labelcellw.setCellValue("Survey Value Part");
        valuecellw.setCellValue(currRowPart);               
        dbStringBuf.append("   </part>\n");     
        dbStringBuf.append("   <pct>\n");
        float partfl = (float)parthold;
        float wholefl = (float)tothold; 
        Integer pctval = Math.round( (partfl/wholefl)*100  );   
        Row row3 = sheet1.createRow(3);
        Cell labelcellp = row3.createCell(0);
        Cell valuecellp = row3.createCell(1);
        labelcellp.setCellValue("Survey Value Pct");
        valuecellp.setCellValue(pctval);
        dbStringBuf.append("     <result>"+pctval+"</result>\n");
        dbStringBuf.append("   </pct>\n");

        stmt2.close();
        con.close();

        FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator(); //checking to make sure value entered in cell is what I'm expecting
        CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("B2"); 
        Row rowtest = sheet1.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
        Cell celltest = rowtest.getCell(cellReference.getCol()); 
        if (celltest!=null) {
            dbStringBuf.append("   <test>\n");
            dbStringBuf.append("     <result>celltest not null/result>\n");
            dbStringBuf.append("   </test>\n");

            dbStringBuf.append("   <test>\n");
            dbStringBuf.append("     <result>"+celltest.getStringCellValue()+"</result>\n");
            dbStringBuf.append("   </test>\n");

        }
        else{
            dbStringBuf.append("   <test>\n");
            dbStringBuf.append("     <result>sorry, null</result>\n");
            dbStringBuf.append("   </test>\n");
        }


        if(outtype.equals("excel")){ //flag from client page determines that we should export Excel file
            res.setContentType("application/ms-excel");
            res.setHeader("Expires:", "0"); // eliminates browser caching
            res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=testxls.xls");
            OutputStream outStream = res.getOutputStream();
            wb.write(outStream);
            outStream.close();
        }   
    } catch(SQLException e)  {      
        bError = true;
        sErrorMessage = "SQLException " + e.getMessage()+" data:"+datatracker+" context:"+contexttracker;
        sErrorCode = "102"; 
    } finally { 
        if (bError) {
            sbResponse.append("    ");appendTag("status","ERROR",sbResponse);sbResponse.append("\n");
            sbResponse.append("    ");appendTag("errorCode",sErrorCode,sbResponse);sbResponse.append("\n");
            sbResponse.append("    ");appendTag("message",sErrorMessage,sbResponse);sbResponse.append("\n");    
        } else {
            sbResponse.append("    ");
            appendTag("status","OK",sbResponse);
            sbResponse.append("\n");
            sbResponse.append( dbStringBuf );
        }
    }   
    if(outtype.equals("xml")){ //flag from client page determines that we should return xml        
        res.setContentType("text/plain");   // CHANGE BACK TO text/xml
        out= res.getWriter();
        sbResponse.append("</response>");
        out.println( sbResponse.toString() );
    }
}
```